# Cent OS 7 NTP Client not syncing via IP address of the NTP server

Tags: centos7, ntp, chrony

I'm trying to update the time of my Cent OS machine by trying to sync it with the NTP server via IP address. This updates the pool on the machine but does not sync the time. I've tried this using both the ntpd and chrony service and changing their respective config files as well, but so far no success. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Your question seems to be solved by installing and running rdate.

I recommend.

yum install -y rdate